# How do I populate an NSMutableArray in one class with another object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ipad

I know this is a simple answer, but I can't seem to find the solution.  I created an object in its own class and I am trying to populate it with data from another class.  For simple data types like NSString, I have no problem, but when trying make an NSMutableArray equal to another NSMutableArray or when I try to populate a NSMutableArray with another objects (like strings), I keep getting exception errors...

Here is the object I am trying to populate:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface RSSFeedList : NSObject {

NSString *subject;
NSMutableArray *rssfeedDetail;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *rssfeedDetail;

@end
```

This is how I was able to populate the NSString 'subject' in another class:

```
rssFeedList.subject = @"test";
```

However, if I follow similar convention within that same class with respect to an Array, it throws an exception:

```
rssFeedList.rssfeedDetail = rssItemDetailArray;
```

**Where rssItemDetailArray is a NSMutableArray that I have built in the same class.**

I have also tried to add items (i tried strings for testing) to the NSMutableArray directly like so to no avail:

```
[rssFeedList.rssfeedDetail addObject:@"test"];
```

Any ideas?? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: And what is the message in the log after an exception?

Comment: -[RSSFeedList setRssfeedDetail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x682f280
2011-02-23 18:29:19.774 TestApp[37344:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RSSFeedList setRssfeedDetail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x682f280'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm almost certain that you've forgotten to synthesize rssfeedDetail.

Comment: The “Treat Warnings as Errors” checkbox is your friend.